# Download application data file from GOOGLE DRIVE

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm storing a database file on Google Drive (application data) but I don't know how to download that file on phone. I know that I should use this function:

```
private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
  try {
    HttpResponse resp =
        service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
            .execute();
    return resp.getContent();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // An error occurred.
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
} else {
  // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
  return null;
}
```

}

and pass this as a file

```
File file = service.files().get(fileid).execute();
```

but I don't know how to get the id of the file that I want. It would be cool if you could help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you upload the database from you application, if you do you can store the id into a `SharedPreference` [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

After you inserted the file, call `file.getFileID();` and store it in a preference like "MyDB_fileID", during the `onStart` or `onResume` load the DB from Google Drive if needed.

Another Choice is to search it (ex. the file is created by a web interface or in another device).

If you know the file name, or the DB is the only file you store on AppData with your application, you can use files.list to retrieve AppData Folder and all its content ([AppData Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata)).

```
String qStr = "'appdata' in parents and title='MyDB'";

//Get the DB (should be 1 or 0 items)
FileList fList=service.files().list().setQ(qStr).execute();
```

It would be best, for performance, to store the `appdata` folder id in a preference instead of let the Google Drive backend do the lookup everytime, as advised in the documentation (you can feel the performance improvements if you use appdata a lot).

The Google Drive Team released a library/service to sync preferences using Google Drive and you can find the source code on GitHub [googledrive/appdatapreferences-android](https://github.com/googledrive/appdatapreferences-android).
At the Google I/O this year there was a really interesting session about [Using Google Drive as a Storage Solution for Android](http://youtu.be/kE-w-ZAtC1k) and it's now available on Youtube.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. By the way - I noticed that when I upload the database file to the app data folder more than one time, the size of the hidden app data files is increasing. I thought that if I upload a file with the same metadata it would override the existing file not create a new one - what can I do about it? Also the name of the application in the Google Drive in Manage Apps is Project Default Service Account - how can I change it?

Comment: Every time you do a file.insert a new file is created, if you need to update a file you need to retrieve the GoogleDrive.File reference to it and then use the file.update command to update a new revision of the file or use other parameters to prevent the creation of a new revision because a new revision will increase the size of the AppData Folder. To change the name of the App you need to change it in the Cloud Console (previously known as Google API Console)